# When does an rvalue reference result in a move vs copy constructor and why?

Tags: c++, move, copy-constructor, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I am confused about explicit usage of the rvalue reference.

Suppose we have a class named ClassX and it has all copy and move methods. When I execute the code below, different copy methods have been invoked (copy constructor and move constructor). But I expect always move constructor is executed. Why copy constructor is invoked when i bind an object explicitly to an rvalue reference and use it as copy object?

```
ClassX c = std::move(object_c);  // Invokes move constructor

ClassX&& cr = std::move(object_c);
ClassX c = cr;  // Invokes copy constructor
```

Comment: If it has a name, it's an lvalue.  `cr` is a name, it's an lvalue.

Comment: An rvalue reference is bound to an rvalue. But whether this reference itself is or is not an rvalue is an entirely independent problem.

Comment: Correct, the code should do `ClassX c = std::move(cr);`.  Keep in mind that `std::move` does **not** itself move anything, it only *allows* a move to occur as-if the variable were an unnamed temporary (such as a return value or result of an expression).  It also allows a variable to be bound to an rvalue reference (usually something that is useful for parameter passing).  If you find this to be confusing, you are not alone; it is confusing.